# loop problem because of 'continue' statement inside 'if' statement in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

i have the following code which runs infinitely when executed. it is fine if i remove the CONTINUE statement. however, with the CONTINUE statement the problem arises. the code is

```
Bn_x=zeros (length(pu_arrival), 1); Bn_x(1)=6;
Br_x=zeros (length(pu_arrival), 1); Br_x(1)=2;
jn1= zeros (length(pu_arrival), 1); jn1(1)=3;
in=zeros (length(pu_arrival), 1);
jn2= zeros (length(pu_arrival), 1); jn2(1)=3;
jr1=zeros (length(pu_arrival), 1);  jr1(1)=1;
ir=zeros (length(pu_arrival), 1); 
jr2=zeros (length(pu_arrival), 1);  jr2(1)=1;
numb_chan_idle_N=0;
numb_chan_idle_R=0;

for i=2:24 %length(pu_arrival)
    if rem(i,2)==0
        [Bn_x,Br_x]=failure3(numb_chan_idle_N,numb_chan_idle_R,in,jn1,jn2,ir,jr1,jr2,Bn_x,Br_x,i);
            continue
    end

end
```

%%%%%%%% The called function  %%%%%%%%%%%%

```
function [Bn_x,Br_x] =failure3(numb_chan_idle_N,numb_chan_idle_R,in,jn1,jn2,ir,jr1,jr2,Bn_x,Br_x,i)
temp=0;
while temp<1
x=randi([1 6]);
if x==1
    if in(i-1)>0
        temp=temp+1;
    end
elseif x==2
    y=randi([1 2]);
    if y==1 
        if jn1(i-1)>0
            temp=temp+1;
        end
    elseif y==2 
        if jn2(i-1)>0
            temp=temp+1; 
        end
    end
elseif x==3  
    if ir(i-1)>0
    end

elseif x==4
    y=randi([1 2]);
    if y==1 
        if jr1(i-1)>0
            temp=temp+1; 
        end

    elseif y==2 
        if jr2(i-1)>0
            temp=temp+1; 
            jr2(i)=jr2(i-1)-1;
            Br_x(i)=Br_x(i-1)-1;
    else
        fprintf('JR2 destined to fail but it is already=%d\n', jr2(i-1))
        continue
        end
    end

elseif x==5
    if numb_chan_idle_N>0
        temp=temp+1; 
    end
elseif x==6
    if numb_chan_idle_R>0
        temp=temp+1; 
    end
end
end
end
```

I want controller to go back to the FOR loop after IF condition satisfies and its inner statement executes. However, the controller never comes out. I can't figure out what is wrong with the code.

Comment: Are you saying that if you cut down `failure3` more you don't see the problem any more? You don't define `numb_chan_idle_N` or `numb_chan_idle_R`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, Actually when I cut down more (failure3), the code gives error. That's why I retained this much of code for posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are generating infinite loops inside `fault3`, the continue statement works as intended, the code just never reaches it.

In the code you given, there are only certain input dependent conditions that will cause `temp=temp+1`, the necessary condition to exit `failure3`. There are certain combinations of numbers (such as the ones you provided as example) that will never trigger any of the `if` conditions inside `failure3`, thus never exiting.

You can easily see this by adding the following to your code:

```
function [Bn_x,Br_x] =failure3(numb_chan_idle_N,numb_chan_idle_R,in,jn1,jn2,ir,jr1,jr2,Bn_x,Br_x,i)
temp=0;
iteration = 0
while temp<1

    iteration=iteration +1

    ...
```

The logic behind `failure3` is broken. In any case, whenever you have an infinite loop `while temp<1`, try to add an extra statement such as `while temp<1 && iteration<500` so you can debug the code better.